# Timber - WooCoommerce email templates

Tags: twig, timber

Hi I'm using Timber and I need to modify the WooCommerce email templates and I've run into a problem:

If I want to use the classical twig template scheme and I place it correctly to the `views/woocommerce/emails/customer-processing-order.twig` it works (=the template is loaded), but I'm missing the template variables needed for actions, namely: `$order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email`

My question is simple - how to get these or how to load PHP email templates instead of twig files in this case?

**UPDATE**

I have found out that for WC emails the things are loading bit differently and having a separate `woocommerce/emails` folder works fine, but for the others doesn't.

Comment: Quick question: do you use the [Timber Integration for WooCommerce](https://github.com/mindkomm/timber-integration-woocommerce)? If yes, what does `{{ dump(wc) }}` give you in your Twig file?

Comment: Did, but not in the case of email. However, I have found out that for WC emails the things are loading bit differently and having a separate `woocommerce/emails` folder works fine

Comment: So what does work, and what doesn’t?